# Multiple migrations have the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration

So I'm trying to deploy my app to Heroku right now but I need to rake my migrations first. However, everytime I rake I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::DuplicateMigrationNameError:

Multiple migrations have the name CreateShoppeInitialSchema
```

I have checked my ENTIRE migrations folder twice and have not found more than one instance of a migration with this name. I tried renaming and also deleting the one instance of this migration that I could find. And I even cleared my heroku database and re-raked and got the same problem. My code runs fine locally.

I asked the question here because all other people who asked this question were able to solve it by deleting their duplicate file; however, I cannot find any such duplicate file. Thank you!

Comment: did you try "heroku run rake db:reset" ?

Comment: I think that this error is not about duplicate filenames, but duplicate *class names* of multiple migrations. You may have the same class name in two migration files. Can you search for `CreateShoppeInitialSchema` through all migration files to see if there are duplicates?

Comment: Had you found a solution?

Comment: did you find the solution? if yes! please share it here. I'm facing same problem after upgrading my rails from 3 to 5.